# Container div and background image with Foundation 4

Tags: zurb-foundation

Just have switched to Foundation 4.
I want to put texture background pattern for body and another texture background for container with all elements. Can't find out how to create this one in proper way.

In pure html+css i would create container element. But in Foundation4 it will have 100% width and overlap body background.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If i add .row class to container i got desired result, but offensive horizontal scroll adds on mobile.
    
        
        ...

How to build this simple layout in F4?

I could style all .row elements, but it will use personal background for every element, which is undesired.

Comment: Can't you use another class, other than container, and then define your background with it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer I gave about CSS and background elements here: [How to use background images in Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751813/zurb-foundation-changing-padding-between-columns)